# How to stop Service, after get location? Android

Tags: android, service, gps, location, alarmmanager

I want, get location every now and then via AlarmManager which turn on service with GPS. 
AlarmManager works correctly, but I have a problem with the stop service.

**First case:**

I get location, but Service works every time.

**ConnectivityReceiver**.java - this is my AlarmManager

```
    public final class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, " onReceive work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("ADRIAN", "onRECEIVE ");
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,LocationUpdaterService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

**LocationUpdaterService**.java - Service

```
public class LocationUpdaterService extends Service implements LocationListener,
                                                               GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
                                                               GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    public LocationUpdaterService() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("ADRIAN", "Wlazlem do onCreate");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).
                        addConnectionCallbacks(this).
                        addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("ADRIAN", "onStartCommand");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location services started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        System.out.println("MyLocationService.onLocationChanged");

        String latitude = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
        String longitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

        Log.i("ADRIAN", "Lat:" + latitude + "Long: " + longitude);

        // do your work here with location
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10); // Update location every second

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            Location loc = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            Log.i("ADRIAN", "onConnected");
        }
        Log.i("ADRIAN", "onConnected 2 ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
//        String latitude = "null";
//        String longitude = "null";

        Toast.makeText(this, "Location services stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Location loc = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if(loc != null) {
//                latitude = Double.toString(loc.getLatitude());
//                longitude = Double.toString(loc.getLongitude());
//                Log.i("ADRIAN", "Lat:" + latitude + "Long: " + longitude);
            }
        }

        Log.i("ADRIAN", "Location services stopped");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

[Screen LOGCAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctmqS.png)

**Second case**

When I added `context.stopService(serviceIntent)` then my application doesn't get location. I tried use `SystemClock.sleep(10000);` but it still works the same.

**ConnectivityReceiver**.java

```
public final class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, " onReceive work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("ADRIAN", "onRECEIVE ");
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,LocationUpdaterService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);

        SystemClock.sleep(10000);
        Log.i("ADRIAN", "STOP SERVICE");
        context.stopService(serviceIntent);

}
```

**LocationUpdaterService.java** - the same as above.

[SCREEN 2 LOGCAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a48aG.png)

What am I doing wrong and How I can fix it?

Comment: try to call `this.stopSelf();` after getting location

Comment: It works! I lost two days on searcing answer, and you do this in a few minutes ;)
Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score -1):

onStartCommand ---> Service.START_STICKY

`@Override
           public void onDestroy() {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);`

```
        locationManager=null;
        super.onDestroy();


        Log.v("STOP_SERVICE", "DONE");

        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        locationManager=null;
```

}

Comment: The question was *"What am I doing wrong and How I can fix it?"*. By just putting code you are certainly not answering the first part. Please add some explanation of the problem and the answer, and also pay attention to formatting.